# Converting pygame surface buffer bytes into numpy array

Tags: python, pygame

Anybody know why this array I created from pygame's `get_buffer` method has the R, G, B, values reversed?  I want to create an array with the colour values in the same order I put them in - like `[8, 16, 32, 0]`.  Have I done something wrong or is this something with the way pygame stores pixel data?

```
>>> import pygame
>>> import pygame.gfxdraw
>>> import numpy as np
>>> background_colour = (1, 1, 1)
>>> width, height = (256, 256)
>>> screen = pygame.Surface((width, height))
>>> pygame.draw.rect(screen, (8, 16, 32), (0, 0, 100, 100), 0)
<rect(0, 0, 100, 100)>
>>> s = screen.get_buffer()
>>> x = np.fromstring(s.raw, dtype='b').reshape(height, width, 4)
>>> x[0, 0]
array([32, 16,  8,  0], dtype=int8)
```

I tried this but I loose the R value:

```
>>> y = x[:, :, 3:0:-1]
>>> y[0, 0]
array([ 0,  8, 16], dtype=int8)
```

(I'm using numpy version 1.8.2 so I don't have `np.flip`).

Answer (score 1):

I realised there is a much better way to do this.  The [`pygame.surfarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module has various methods that actually create numpy arrays for you!

```
>>> x3 = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(screen)
>>> x3.shape
(256, 256, 3)
>>> x3[0, 0]
array([ 8, 16, 32], dtype=uint8)
```